# Text wont align right

Tags: html, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I cant get my text to align right:

```
    #login_status
    {
           font-size: 1.2em;
           text-align: right;
           display: block;
           float:right;

    }
```

Here is the other pertinent css:

```
    #logo 
    {
           position: absolute;
           top: 15%;
           margin-left: 1em;
    }

    #login_status
    {
           font-size: 1.2em;
           text-align: right;
           display: block;
           float:right;

    }

    #header_container
    {
        background: #7fc041;
        height: 7.4em;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }

    #header_text 
    {
        margin-left: 9.75em;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: White;
        font-style: italic;
    }
```

and the html/server controls:

```
<div id="header_container">        
    <div id="header">
        <div id="headerBar">
            <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo"/> 
            <span id="header_text">Scrum Reports</span>
      <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" CssClass="login_status" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide the html that is output to the client

Comment: You have no ID `login_status` in your HTML, you have a class however `.login_status`

Comment: In addition to providing the final HTML, I assume `CssClass` outputs a `class` attribute. So you will probably want to change `#login_status` in your CSS to: `.login_status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm no asp.net expert, but I see you using `#login_status` with `text-align: right` and `CssClass="login_status"`, which seems to me like it would output

```
<div class="login_status">
```

Thus you should either change `#login_status` to `.login_status`, or have it set the *id* rather than the class because the styles seem to be fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/mzUTW/